# javafx Error when creating a new project in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

When I try to create a new JavaFX application using Netbeans, I get a error message. I'll appreciate any tips on how to resolve it. 
[image]

Comment: have you installed java correctly ? Look [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/72/java/javafx-setup.html) for a tutorial on how to set up **Netbeans** for *JavaFX*

Comment: Are you on linux-systems? If you are using OpenJDK, please install OpenJFX too.